# Increase max file upload size for SilverStripe site

Tags: php, .htaccess, silverstripe, filesize

I am working on increasing the max upload file size for a SilverStripe site as I want the new limit to be 20 MB instead of 2 MB. I have placed this line of code in the root .htaccess file for the project:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

This works to some extent. It has increased the upload size limit, but only to 8 MB. I removed this line of code and tried uploading a large file again and the "file size exceeds 2 MB" error returned. So, what I have in place does work but only increases the file size limit to 8 MB.

I have been reading that there can be a php.ini file included in the project to increase the file size limit as well, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it through just the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this problem is because you've not set your `post_max_size`. The `post_max_size` defaults to 8mb. So you need to do the following:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

You can obviously edit the `post_max_size` to something more suitable to what you need.

Comment: I didn't even think about that--but that did fix the problem! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

This 100% work in v4

Your problem is indeed related to php.ini.

In php.ini there is a section related to file uploads that will have the following line in it;

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Change the 2M to be something more in line with what you need, then restart apache and you should be good to go.

It is also possible (though i have not tried this yet) to put the following line in to the .htaccess.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Hope that helps.